# Why does this recursive copy function copy all files into every directory above the correct one?

Tags: python, recursion, os.walk

I write a function to copy files from  directory A to directory B recursive. 
The code is like this:

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
from os.path import join, exists

def copy_file(src, dest):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
        if len(dirs) > 0:
            for di in dirs:
                copy_file(join(path, di), join(dest,  di))

        if not exists(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)
        for fi in files:
            shutil.copy(join(path, fi), dest)
```

In my test, the input args are like this:

```
src = d:/dev
```

and it have one sub directory named `py`. Also, `py` has a sub directory named `test`

```
dest = d:/dev_bak
```

So, when i test my code, something strange happened.
In my `dest` directory which is `d:/dev_bak`, three sub directories are created.
That is: `d:/dev_bak/py`; `d:/dev_bak/py/test`; `d:/dev_bak/test`.

In my design, the structure of `dev_bak` will be same as `dev`. So, why this happened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily diagnose this by putting

```
    print path, dirs, files
```

right below

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
```

Essentially, you're recursing twice.

By itself, `os.walk` descends into subdirectories. You're double-descending by recursively calling your own function. Here is some example output from that `print` statement:

```
>>> copy_file("c:\Intel", "c:\Intel-Bak")
c:\Intel ['ExtremeGraphics', 'Logs'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics ['CUI'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI ['Resource'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI ['Resource'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\Logs [] ['IntelChipset.log', 'IntelControlCenter.log', 'IntelGFX.log', 'IntelGFXCoin.log']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics ['CUI'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI ['Resource'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI ['Resource'] []
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource [] ['Intel\xae Graphics and Media Control Panel.lnk', 'Intel\xae HD Graphics.lnk']
c:\Intel\Logs [] ['IntelChipset.log', 'IntelControlCenter.log', 'IntelGFX.log', 'IntelGFXCoin.log']
```

As you can see, the directories get visited twice.

You should fix the logic of your program so it visits each directory only once, but theoretically you could just ignore any directory you've already been to:

```
visited = []
def copy_file(src, dest):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
        if path not in visited:
            for di in dirs:
                print dest, di
                copy_file(join(path, di), join(dest,  di))
            if not exists(dest):
                os.makedirs(dest)
            for fi in files:
                shutil.copy(join(path, fi), dest)
            visited.append(path)
```

Comment: thanks. But i got another question. When I read the doc of os.walk(), they say "When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames;"

Comment: @linuxlsx Right. By iterating over `dirs` and removing every directory in it, you leave it empty. So `os.walk` doesn't descend at all -- the only visits to the subdirs are done by your recursive call. You've turned `os.walk` into a fancy `os.listdir`. I'm not sure what you mean by "why does it work".

Answer (score 0):

The [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module already has a copytree function which will copy directories recursively. You might want to use it instead of providing your own implementation.

Comment: This is most likely for a class or self-education.

Comment: Exactly, the copytree() do a great job, but there are something different with my issue. copytree request the destination directory must not exist, in my design, the destination directory maybe have existed.