# Recursively copy and flatten a directory with python

Tags: python, batch-file, recursion

I have a batch file thats goes through several hundred nested directorys and copies all the files out into one destination (effectively flattening a copy of the source).  My batch file is:

```
set source="X:\"

set destination="Y:\"

for /R %source% %%f in (*.*)  do xcopy  "%%f" %destination% /D /Y
```

Very simple but does what i need it to.  Now i need a solution that will do the same thing in python.  Im very new to python and cant even in theory figure out how this would work.  I assume i would need to os.walk through all the nested folders to get to the files and somehow copy those out??? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Through Google I have found how to go through directories recursively and how to copy files, but i cant find any solution that ties the two together.  Im currently using python2 (2.7).

Comment: Several good suggestions here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110417/why-does-this-recursive-copy-function-copy-all-files-into-every-directory-above

Comment: `Through Google I have found how to go through directories recursively and how to copy files, but i cant find any solution that ties the two together` - errr... as you go through each file in each directory, you issue the copy command on it... You need to be a bit more specific... at the moment this is a "give me some code" question

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.walk) to get a flat iterator over all files in a directory tree:

```
def find_files(root):
    for d, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(d, f)
```

Now you can use [`shutil.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) on each of the files to copy them to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you found how to walk the directory recursively, and how to copy files.

Try writing a program that simply prints out the path of each file it sees.

Once you have that working, just replace the `print` line with your copy function. No magic required!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is close to what you're looking for:

```
$ cat copy-flatten
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import os
import sys
import shutil

assert sys.argv[2:]
assert not sys.argv[3:]

source_dir = sys.argv[1]
destination_dir = sys.argv[2]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for filename in files:
        source_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        destination_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, filename)
        print('Copying {} to {}'.format(source_path, destination_path))
        shutil.copy(source_path, destination_path)

$ cat Makefile

go:
        rm -rf ./dest
        mkdir -p ./dest
        ./copy-flatten /usr/src ./dest

clean:
        rm -rf ./dest
```